# Cannot find 64-bit Teradata OLE DB

Tags: sql-server, teradata

I am trying to pull data from Teradata in SSMS. I have the linked server set up in my Server Objects but when I try to connect it , I get an error stating

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "XYZ".

I tried to find the OLE DB for Teradata for 64-bit but it seems Teradata hasn't released the 64-bit yet. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Try using the [.Net provider](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/net-data-provider-for-teradata). It supports 32 and 64 bit Windows.